# Change of basis matrix derivation issue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, change-of-basis

can someone help me with this?

Let $E$ be a $n$ finite dimension vector space and let $B = \{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$, $B' = \{e'_1,e'_2,...,e'_n\}$ two different basis.

Now I can write any vector $v \in  E$ as a linear combination of either basis:

$ v = v_1e_1 + v_2e_1 + ... + v_ne_n = v'_1e'_1 + v'_2e'_1 + ... + v'_ne'_n$

being $v_i$ and $v'_i$ the components of the vector for each basis. And I also can write that as a matrix product

$\begin{pmatrix}  e_1  & e_2 & ... & e_n  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  v_1  \\ v_2 \\ ... \\ v_n  \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}  e'_1  & e'_2 & ... & e'_n  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  v'_1  \\ v'_2 \\ ... \\ v'_n  \end{pmatrix} $

Now I perform a change of basis with the matrix:

$ \begin{pmatrix}  e'_1  & e'_2 & ... &  e'_n  \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}  e_1  & e_2 & ... & e_n  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  a_{11} & a_{21} & ... & a_{n1} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & ... & a_{n2} \\  ... & ... & ... & ... \\ a_{1n} & a_{2n} & ... & a_{nn} \\\end{pmatrix}$

and substituting I get

$\begin{pmatrix}  e_1  & e_2 & ... & e_n  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  a_{11} & a_{21} & ... & a_{n1} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & ... & a_{n2} \\  ... & ... & ... & ... \\ a_{1n} & a_{2n} & ... & a_{nn} \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  v'_1  \\ v'_2 \\ ... \\ v'_n  \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}  e_1  & e_2 & ... & e_n  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  v_1  \\ v_2 \\ ... \\ v_n  \end{pmatrix} $

But those are the component of the vector in the $B$ basis so:

$\begin{pmatrix}  v_1  \\ v_2 \\ ... \\ v_n  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  a_{11} & a_{21} & ... & a_{n1} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & ... & a_{n2} \\  ... & ... & ... & ... \\ a_{1n} & a_{2n} & ... & a_{nn} \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  v'_1  \\ v'_2 \\ ... \\ v'_n  \end{pmatrix}  $

It seems like I have simplified the $\begin{pmatrix}  e_1  & e_2 & ... & e_n  \end{pmatrix}$ at both sides of the equation. The thing is that, how can this be true since $\begin{pmatrix}  e_1  & e_2 & ... & e_n  \end{pmatrix}$ is not a square matrix and therefore it has no inverse matrix? Or maybe my derivation is just wrong...

Comment: As you wrote, they are the components of $v$ in the basis $\pmatrix{e_1&e_2&\cdots&e_n}$, therefore the same. The only thing you need is the uniqueness of presentation of vector as linear combination of basis vectors, which is guaranteed by linear independence of basis.

Comment: Yes I know that. But my question is if I could just simplify the identity by mutiplying both sides of the equation by the inverse of $(e_1 ~ e_2 ... e_n)$ because if so I would get the same result.

Comment: In general the elements $e_k, e_k'$ are elements of some arbitrary vector space, so you would use the fact that they are basis to conclude equality, not multiplying by an inverse.

Comment: Yeah @copper.hat and that's what I have used in the derivation. What I'm trying to say is that in practical terms is the same as I had multiplied by some inverse matrix and cancelled out the row matrix of $e$ vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question. Note that each $e_i$ is a 'vector', not just a scalar. So the matrix $\pmatrix{e_1&e_2&\cdots&e_n}$ is a $n\times n$ square matrix. And by linear independence, the matrix has nonzero determinant and therefore invertible. Thus you can derive the equation by cancelling, too.